# Brute-forcing Pattern Locks in Mobile with Python and Keyboard Inputs

Tags: python, android, hid

I am currently working on a Python program to brute force pattern locks on a mobile device, similar to the approach outlined in this [Android-PIN-Bruteforce](https://github.com/urbanadventurer/Android-PIN-Bruteforce). However, instead of cracking a numeric PIN, I am interested in simulating pattern input.

I have successfully implemented the basic brute-forcing logic in Python, but I am facing challenges in finding a way to draw the pattern programmatically. My goal is to use the keyboard as an input method to simulate the pattern drawing on the mobile device.

Is there any Python library or method that allows me to capture keyboard inputs to represent the pattern on the mobile device's screen? How can I effectively translate keyboard inputs to the pattern drawing gestures, considering the typical 3x3 grid layout of mobile pattern locks?

Any guidance or code examples on how to achieve this keyboard-based pattern drawing for mobile pattern locks in Python would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Even though I am not entirely sure, I think it might be possible to simulate mouse movements through ADB (Android Debug Bridge). However, this method requires USB debugging to be turned on, which may not always be feasible.
Therefore, I am seeking a more general method to simulate mouse inputs using the keyboard or any other suggestions to tackle this problem effectively.